# How to create multiple sections based on array of objects with date?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to make a list with multiple section headers and items based on a date field of a list of items. What is the best way to do this programmatically?

```
var registrants:[Registration] = [Registration(name:"Joe", date:12/15/2020),Registration(name:"Billy", date:11/12/2020),Registration(name:"Cameron", date:11/10/2020)]
```

Usually I hardcode and use only foreach loop for items in one specific section like the following:

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("December 2020")) {
       ForEach(...)
    }
    Section(header: Text("November 2020")) {
       ForEach(...)
    }
    Section(header: Text("October 2020")) {
       ForEach(...)
    }
}
```

Am looking for a smarter way to do this...

Comment: wrap those sections in a ForEach too

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63193327/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically create sections in a SwiftUI List/ForEach and avoid "Unable to infer complex closure return type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574847/how-to-dynamically-create-sections-in-a-swiftui-list-foreach-and-avoid-unable-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use in a ForEach your data should be `Identifiable` or there should be some way you can specify id.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var registrants:[Registration] = [Registration(name:"Joe", date:"12/15/2020"),Registration(name:"Billy", date:"11/12/2020"),Registration(name:"Cameron", date:"11/10/2020")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(registrants) { (registration) in //<=Here
                Section(header: Text(registration.date)) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in
                        Text("item \(item)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Registration : Identifiable{ //<= here
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var date: String
}
```